# Check if a word appears twice with regex

Tags: regex, cpu-word, repeat

I want to check with regex if the word **link** appears twice in a sentence.

The sentence goes: "This link is invalid. Try the link below." --> here I need the regex to check if "link" appears twice.

This is my first time trying regex and I only understood the grouping so far like `\b(link)\b`. With this I can check if the word link even appears but I need to know if it appears twice.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @tobias_k It shows that `.*` can be used to match any chars between two same words. `\blink\b.*\blink\b` will do for the time being, unless there is something else.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Never mind, I read the question as check whether _any_ word appears twice, but if OP just wants to check for "link", the same can be used as for "http".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
\b(link)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)
```

This gives you the first occurrence of the duplicate word.

Tested it with your sentence here: https://regex101.com/r/2zGSKj/2

A shorter solution without groups would simply be

```
\blink\b.*\blink\b
```

Tested it here: https://regex101.com/r/2zGSKj/3

Comment: Not all regex libraries allow lookaheads and/or backreferences.

Comment: @BlueCat: It shows only one, but only when the word link appears twice. So you have your check.